# Cakephp Fatal Error when including Javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, fatal-error

I am including preffify.js in my CakePHP theme's view file which generates url for prettify as http://localhost/thecontrolist/theme/coco/libs/prettify/prettify.js. As explained [in this link](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/2316) CakePHP serves the file as PHP. The problem is this that prettify.js is having a string <?= which equals short echo call hence it 
causes to generate a Fatal error, as follows:

```
Fatal Error
Error: syntax error, unexpected '?' 
File: C:\wamp\www\thecontrolist\app\View\Themed\coco\webroot\libs\prettify\prettify.js  
Line: 11

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\fatal_error.ctp
```

Is there a workaround for this?

I am using CakePHP 2.5.5.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266294/sharing-tinymce-plugin-across-multiple-applications/24283046#24283046

Comment: I see that this question has been marked as duplicate. I do agree that technically it is but for the "symptom-wise" or in other words "search term-wise" former does not seem to relate to it and that's why I could not find an answer until I posted it for myself. May be I did't spend generous time searching for  on the stackoverflow but then you think that asking is something similar when you don't have a quick solution. And if you don't believe me try to look at the Related entries. I think I explained this question very simply but you don't see your suggested answer in the Related

Comment: It seems like you have a space between '<' and '?'.  It should be <?= , not < ?= .  You are right about duplicate flag.  This site needs protection from its protectors

Comment: @ArvindK I don't think that mplungjan will "hear" you. I would agree that the linked question is not the perfect canonical one as it's very TinyMCEish, which is why I hesitated with marking this as a duplicate.

Comment: Anyways, try for example http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcakephp%5D+asset+php+tag (or more specific http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcakephp%5D+%5Bjavascript%5D+asset+php+tag) or https://www.google.com/search?q=cakephp+asset+syntax+error%2C+unexpected+%27%3F%27 In terms of searchability, it's relatively easy to find, however it requires some experience in "how to search effectively", and from just looking at the question, it might not be obvious to anyone to figure that this is the same problem they are experiencing.

Comment: Another problem related to this issue. I did create a new filter as described in the "answer" and there is now problem with css files. They are not interpreted as CSS now but as text now breaking overall website. Anyone there? Do I post it as a new question?