# CakePHP theme CSS and JS broken after adding a Asset filter fix

Tags: javascript, php, css, cakephp, themes

I am using CakePHP 2.5.5

I had a problem and I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29250774/cakephp-fatal-error-when-including-javascript-file). I was suggested an answer described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266294/sharing-tinymce-plugin-across-multiple-applications/).

Now I have another problem related to this issue. I did create a new filter as described in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266294/sharing-tinymce-plugin-across-multiple-applications/) and there is now problem with CSS and Javascript files located in the theme folder. The CSS and Javascript files in theme are not interpreted as native "type" now but as **raw HTML text** (image attached) causing to break overall website. If i remove the filter it causes JS to interpret as PHP and if I add it the CSS and Javascript do not work. Something to do with headers but could not figure it out. What should I do now?

[image]

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question, also have another look at the linked answer, I've updated it again to make it even more clear that everything around the change needs to be reimplemented.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just *blindly* [copied the code from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266294/sharing-tinymce-plugin-across-multiple-applications/) instead of trying to understand what it does before? *Never do that*.

```
$contentType = 'application/octetstream';
```

I guess this is the reason, you need to send the right content type for your assets.